# Add image over cell such that it should not be edited by other user except owner & assign script to run when user click

Tags: image, google-sheets, insert, locking

In Google sheets, I would like to add an image and make it static such that other users cannot edit or delete the image similar to lock image in Google slides. Is there a way to lock image from editing? Or any workaround?

Note: I am not asking for image in cell.

**Edit:** I tried to insert image in the cell using =IMAGE("url") and locked the cell. Yes this partly solves my problem. However I need this image to be assigned a script/macro so that when a user clicks on it, it should run a script.

For assigning the script, I tried to solve it by adding a transparent drawing object that overlayed on to the image and assigned the macro script but when i reload the sheet, the transparent object keeps moving. Can I set the drawing object to a standard/default position or lock the drawing object too (idea is that, the user should be able to move any of the object i.e image or the drawing object)

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: For example, how about protecting the cell which has the formula of `=IMAGE(imageURL)`? By this, other users cannot remove the image, because the cell is protected. I post it as a comment because I'm not sure your actual goal. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the comment. I too had that as a backup if I don't find any solution

Comment: @User1090 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Not possible - @Tanaike's suggestion is the only workaround I am aware of here.

Comment: I tried that option but what about if I have to assign script for it to run when clicked

Comment: @User1090 You should add that as a requirement or post a new question. Also, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I have edited the questions with updated requirement and optios I tried and failed